# "Firebase Storage", for images - but, get the actual URL?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

Sending an image to the "Firebase Storage" system ...

```
sr ... a StorageReference (ie, FIRStorageReference)
let task = sr.putData(data)
task.observe(.success) { [index] snapshot in
    guard let downloadURL: URL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()
    else { .. err }
```

However, the end result is URLs, which are like this:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/someapp.com/o/0.jpg?alt=media&token=113150a1-8152-666-666-fd00dc9e8734

It works absolutely perfectly - however -

that URL is simply *not a URL of a jpeg* - it's just a URL of a file.  Clicking  on it results in you **getting a file download of the jpeg**.

This seems incredible - with all other online storage (AWS etc), you just get "an actual URL of a jpeg".

Is there a solution here?

---

As BC asked below, looking at the headers:

```
$ cat headers.txt
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2Ur3b5CNUIWWZdwn-666slsPqTjJT3GF83m6sJ-mzx...666
Expires: Sat, 29 Jul 2017 23:22:38 GMT
Date: Sat, 29 Jul 2017 23:22:38 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Sat, 29 Jul 2017 18:55:21 GMT
ETag: "9e4491f86bd78ee62d241d962893f666"
x-goog-generation: 1501354521940666
x-goog-metageneration: 1
x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
x-goog-stored-content-length: 8992
x-goog-meta-firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: cd9e7a4b-6666-666-b6b8-5a700bed2e64
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: inline; filename*=utf-8''0.jpg
x-goog-hash: crc32c=z72qJQ==
x-goog-hash: md5=nkSR+GvXjuYtJB2WKJP6666==
x-goog-storage-class: STANDARD
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 8992
Server: UploadServer
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"
```

Comment: Could you share the code that was used to upload the image and get that URL?

Comment: You're probably being redirected. Try "curl -D 'headers.txt' URL" to see exactly how.

Comment: So, what does happen when you run `curl -D headers.txt 'URL' > output.txt`? What are the contents of headers.txt and output.txt? Remember, as long as the servers sets the MIME-type to "image/jpeg", it doesn't matter what the file extension is. It's also possible the server is setting MIME-type to "octet-stream" or something.

Comment: good one @barrycarter it's there

Comment: good one @DougStevenson it's there

Answer (score 1):

Your code is uploading raw binary data to Storage without regarding its content type.  The Storage SDK is not going to attempt to interpret the contents of that NSData blob when using `putData`.  However, the content type *will* be inferred if using `putFile`.

If you need to use `putData`, instead try [specifying some metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#add_file_metadata) along with the upload with `putData:metadata:`.

In the Firebase console, you can check the content type of the file uploaded by selecting it.  It should read image/jpeg in the right hand panel as well.